# Span of Integer Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, vectors, linear-transformations

This question relates to linear combinations of vectors; however, vectors can only be scaled by integer values.  This means that if we have two vectors $\binom{a}{b}$ and $\binom{c}{d}$, we can only have $$x\binom{a}{b} + y\binom{c}{d},$$ where $a, b, c, d, x,y\in \mathbb{Z}.$

I was wondering how to determine when linear combinations of two vectors will span $\mathbb{Z^2}$.   I know that if the second vector is a multiple of the first, this will not be true, but I'm not sure about the other cases.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! This depends on whether $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c\\d \end{pmatrix}$  are in $\mathbf Z^2$.

Comment: Iff $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$? Do I understand you correctly, are you asking when $\{x \cdot \binom{a}{b} + y \cdot \binom{a}{b} \colon x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, a, b, c, d are also in the set of integers.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov Yes, this is my question.

Comment: @RamanConjecture I deleted my answer because I initially thought you were referring to binomial coeffecients and not column vectors there

Comment: What happens if the second vector is a multiple of the first?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz, then you can only have $k\binom{a}{b}$ where $k, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}.$  That means that you cannot reach all points in the Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: @RamanConjecture But your question asks whether  $k\binom{a}{b}$ will be element of $\mathbf Z^2$ which is true

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb... I should change the question to say "the span of the linear combinations of two vectors will be $\mathbb{Z^2}.$"

Comment: @RamanConjecture You can rephrase it like "when will linear combinations of two vectors span $\mathbf Z^2$"

Comment: @RamanConjecture Anyway just rewrite it as matrix multiplication with $\binom{x}{y}$. When is this equal to any vector in $\mathbf Z^2$? When Your matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim**: $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$ span the whole $\mathbb Z^2=M_{12}(\mathbb Z)$ if and only if $\det\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]=ad-bc=\pm 1$.

**Proof sketch**: basically, the span is the whole of $\mathbb Z^2$ if and only if $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ can be represented as linear combinations of $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$. However:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=z\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$$

is equivalent to:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}x&z\\y&t\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]=I$$

so existence of $\left[\begin{matrix}x&z\\y&t\end{matrix}\right]$ implies that $\det\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]=\pm 1$, and, conversely, if $\det\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]=\pm 1$, then the inverse $\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}$ is easily shown to be an integral matrix.

**Note**: Notice that, using the same logic, one can conclude that $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent if and only if $\det\left[\begin{matrix}a&c\\b&d\end{matrix}\right]=ad-bc\ne 0$. Thus, in  the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z^2$ there are pairs of "vectors" which are linearly independent but don't span the whole module.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Note that $$x\binom{a}{b} + y\binom{c}{d} =\binom{ax+cy}{bx+dy}.$$

By Bezout's lemma, as long as gcd(a, c) = 1 and gcd(b, d) = 1, the resulting vector can take on value in $\mathbb{Z^2}.$

Is this sufficient?

Comment: It is not. $ad-bc$ must be $\pm 1$, which implies your condition, but is not equivalent to it.